# Ubuntu 18.04 - Fresh Install - Interface Hangs/Freezes when changing focus

Tags: 18.04

Every time that i change the focus on notifications (like basic authentication ones) using tab, or in any kind of form (like the Signup form from AskUbuntu), the computer hangs for like, 1 sec, and then it gives the control back. It's annoying as hell [sorry for the swearing]. I notice that, when this happens, Xorg have a CPU spike.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

> Fresh Install 18.04 ( 4.15.0-23-generic )

I'd tried to change between lightdm, sddm and gdm3 and nothing worked.

But then I switched to Plasma (KDE), everything working just fine.

I know that changing from Gnome to Plasma maybe its not a option for you, but for me was and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the issue on a system upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, where it appeared to be related to the `radeon` kernel module, or possibly to the fact that the `radeon` and `amdgpu` kernel modules were both loaded.   When the `radeon` module was blacklisted, the issue was resolved.

To blacklist the module, append `modprobe.blacklist=radeon` to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.  Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Clearly, blacklisting a kernel module that would otherwise be appropriate for the graphics card in the system is a workaround for an issue elsewhere.  You could try logging in to a Unity session (via the settings wheel next to the login button), to see if the fault isn't with the Gnome Shell.

Both aren't proper solutions, but may help pinpoint the bug.